# UnicodeDecodeError when logging an Exception in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, unicode

I'm using Python 2.7.9. x32 on Win7 x64.

When I'm logging an Exception containing Umlauts, I always receive
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)`

My example code is:

```
except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Error loading SCMTool for repository '
                          '%s (ID %d): %s' % (repo.name, repo.id, e),
                          exc_info=1)
```

The Exception being logged is `WindowsError: [Error 267] Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig`.
The Problem is based on the "ung**Ü**ltig" umlaut.

After removing the last `%s` and the `e` it works without a problem.

This happens everytime an exception is logged, therefore changing every logger is no alternative.

Does anyone have an idea how to make Exception return a unicode string globally?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to interpolate a `unicode` object into a `str` template, triggering an implicit encoding.

Use a `unicode` template; `logging` can handle Unicode just fine:

```
logging.error(u'Error loading SCMTool for repository '
              '%s (ID %d): %s' % (repo.name, repo.id, e),
              exc_info=1)
```

Two additional tips:

- You don't have to do the interpolation yourself; if you pass in the 3 elements to interpolate as separate arguments, `logging` will interpolate for you, but only if the message is actually going to be emitted.
- If you use `logging.exception()` the message is logged at the `ERROR` level and `exc_info` is set for you; it gets you the same result but is more easily recognised when reading your code later. Either way, the exception is *already included* in that case, no need to include it again in the message.

As such, I'd use:

```
logging.exception(
    'Error loading SCMTool for repository %s (ID %d)',
    repo.name, repo.id)
```

Comment: This is not really my code, I'm using Reviewboard which contains a lot files with multiple Exception loggings.

Is there no more central way? Where I do not have to touch all files.

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug with the Reviewboard project then?

Comment: There is no more 'central' way, this is a bug with how exceptions are being handled.

Comment: The Problem is very confusing, on another Windows installation it does not throw the UDE exception. Do you know a possible reason for that? Wrong encoding of cmd or something?

Comment: @Seega make sure it is a UDE and not a UEE (encode); printing to windows consoles is notoriously problematic. There is also Python 2 vs. 3 and worst case, someone tried to 'fix' things by using `sys.setdefaultencoding()` (which just plasters over the problem but only leads to harder to debug problems later).

Comment: Both are running Python 2.7.9 with all same dependencies. I also think it is a console problem. But I cannot reproduce the problem in a single Python command

Comment: @Seega: the exception should give you a hint at least, the traceback will tell you what expressions were executed. Extract the variable values at that point, isolate the exact part of the expression responsible and then go from there.

Comment: I found the root cause.
On one maschine I'M using Win7 english (here it works)
And on the other german (Doesn't work).  

With your fix, the Exception ``WindowsError: [Error 267] Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig' is logged.``  

This contains an `Ü` which cannot be encoded to ``ascii``.  

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Seega: There can be any number of reasons the directory name is invalid. Debug that with `os.listdir()` of the parent directory perhaps. Is the pathname in Unicode or encoded to the [filesystem encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding)?

Comment: The reason of the exception is clear. But the exception message broke the code because of the "ü" in "ungültig" everything fine.

Comment: @Seega: ah, I see what you mean, I misunderstood. Glad it is now working! :-D